# Program to update the database table from the parameter with the excel sheet from select option in ABAP

Tags: abap

Will come directly to the question.

Have 2 parameter like filename and table name. The requirement is to upload the data from the excel sheet to the database table enter in the other parameter. This should be in run time. No hardcoding of field names and that program should be flexible enough to suite any table. Please help.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What @hering said - plus, updating arbitrary database tables directly is usually a bad idea. There's a reason why we have things like LSMW.

Comment: Do you have a problem with a Excel data reading or with a saving to a DB-table. The second question, have you read the data from a XLS-file or from Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible approaches:

1. Dynamic code generation -- write a program which writes a program
2. Use dynamic type tools

For 1. try googling

For 2. see https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Example+-+create+a+dynamic+internal+table - this wiki shows a way (not sure if it is overkill as it creates the type from scratch whereas any table in your SAP system is already a defined type in the Data Dictionary).

You can do easily reference a parameterised table in Open SQL e.g. MODIFY (p_tab) ...

Perhaps you could do a generic SPLIT of a line read in from file by the delimiter into a table of fields - you can then use ASSIGN COMPONENT to match the fields you have read in to the fields in your internal type.

If you are doing this I think a white list of allowed tables would be wise - and auth checks. Otherwise someone could upload SAP standard tables with no authorisation.